# WordPress WooCommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I can't fetch data using Ionic REST API for WooCommerce. But link is fetching data through URL. I tried everything but not working. I check in console it shows me an error in network fetch failed.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
Woocommerce : any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
this.Woocommerce = WC ({

url : "https://freelancerdemoweb.000webhostapp.com",
consumerKey : "ck_b34a9b3d45b59e519cabf6ac64576f1c42365039",
consumerSecret : "cs_b534fca91deeffef9403e4b2c7846d2ad20c7253"
}); 

  this.Woocommerce.get('products/99', function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
  }) 
}

}
```

console :

polyfills.js:3 OPTIONS https://freelancerdemoweb.000webhostapp.com/wc-api/v3/products/99 0 ()

Comment: its working through this url all products are fetching https://freelancerdemoweb.000webhostapp.com/wc-api/v3/products/99

Comment: can u add the full error code pls ?